# JFreeChart renderers (layers) order

Tags: java, jfreechart

Is it possible to set up the order of drawn renderers (layers) or request 'bring to front' on some renderer?

Such functionality would be useful when you combine areas with lines and you want have lines always 'on top'.

Comment: Methods that add a `Marker` to a plot can specify the `Layer`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For both the CategoryPlot and XYPlot classes, the primary dataset is rendered last so it will appear at the "front".  There is an option to reverse the order in which the datasets are rendered (in the case of plots having multiple datasets) via the [setDatasetRenderingOrder()](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/XYPlot.html#setDatasetRenderingOrder%28org.jfree.chart.plot.DatasetRenderingOrder%29) method.  It's not quite as flexible as a "bring-to-front" option, but it does give a limited amount of control.

Comment: Yes sure that is in the documentation also, but the problem with flexibility is in case when I have for instance three series and each of them I can render either as a line or as an area (what I do by changing the renderer for the dataset). In such a case sometimes can happen that area will hide the line. So I would like to have possibility to 'bring to front' all lines. The only way to do that which come into my mind is to create two datasets for one 'real data set' and for each dataset create a renderer, and add line renderers first or last (depending on datasetRenderingOrder you mentioned).

Comment: However this is a bit redundant because I have to create two datasets for one real data set.